# Xcode 6 Key Bindings Directory

Tags: ios, xcode, key-bindings

I have custom Keybinding file `foo.idekeybindings`. It seems like directory has been changed? Does anybody can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is on ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/KeyBindings